# FAKE build fails creating nuget package on osx under mono

Tags: macos, f#, mono, nuget, f#-fake

I'm using the `FAKE` build tool on OSX under `mono` as part of my build chain.

All toolchains have been installed using `homebrew`.

Part of the build is to bundle up release artefacts in a `nuget` package - which is being handled in the `CreatePackage` target of my `build.fsx` build file.

The build file is being run from a wrapper `bash` script as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export EnableNuGetPackageRestore=true
nuget "Install" "FAKE" "-OutputDirectory" "./build/packages" “-ExcludeVersion"
nuget "Install" "FSharp.Data" "-OutputDirectory" "./build/packages" "-ExcludeVersion"
mono "./build/packages/FAKE/tools/Fake.exe" build.fsx "$1"
```

When I run this initially I get the following error:

```
Cannot open assembly '***/tools/NuGet/NuGet.exe': No such file or directory.
```

My attempt at fixing this has just been to create the expected directory structure, and copy over the `nuget.exe` assembly from its `brew` installation directory.

Running the build at this point then gives the following error:

```
System.Exception: Error during NuGet package creation. ***/tools/NuGet/nuget.exe pack -Version 1.0.0 -OutputDirect
Method 'String.Format' not found.
```

For completeness, the CreatePackage target of my `build.fsx` build file is as follows (truncated):

```
Target "CreatePackage" (fun _ ->
        projectName
        |> sprintf "%s.nuspec"
        |> NuGet (fun p ->
        {p with
                Authors = authors
                Project = packageName
                Description = projectDescription
                OutputPath = deployDir
                WorkingDir = root
                Version = version
                Dependencies = dependenciesWithVersion
                Files = [(@"build/tmp/**", Some "lib", None)
                        (@"MyProject/dsc/modules/**/*", Some "dsc", None)
                        (@"MyProject/dsc/manifests/*", Some "dsc", None)
                        (@"MyProject/Install/*", Some "tools", None)]
                Publish = false })
)
```

Comment: I'm afraind I don't know much about NuGet, but I have another idea. Is using NuGet a requirement for your project? Because in my experience, working with [Paket](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/) is FAR nicer than NuGet. Instead of XML files, you can write a simple text file with likes like "nuget FAKE" and "nuget FSharp.Data" and Paket manages your dependencies. To see Paket in action, clone https://github.com/fsprojects/ProjectScaffold and run its `build.sh` script. Then look at `build.sh` and `build.fsx` and you'll have some good examples to copy.

Comment: And Paket can create NuGet packages just fine, via the `paket pack` command. I haven't used that command yet, so I can't do better than to point you to the [`paket pack` documentation](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/paket-pack.html).

Comment: No real depedency on nuget - just need to get the deployment artefacts (bins, config, etc) all packaged up and installable on the target Windows servers as an installable unit (callable from the AWS user-data bootstrapper). I'll take a look at Paket - sounds promising. Many thanks the the suggestion.